# is there a continuous surjective map $f : T \rightarrow T$ such that the induced homomorphism $f^* : H1(T,x) \rightarrow H1(T,x)$is the zero-map.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $T = \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ be a torus and $x \in T$. Prove or disprove: There exists a continuous
surjective map $f : T \rightarrow T$ such that the induced homomorphism $f^* : H_1(T,x) \rightarrow
H_1(T,x)$is the zero-map.

I have no idea how to solve this kind of problems. All I know is that since the fundamental group of the torus is abelian we may think of $f^*$ as a map of fundamental groups instead. We can also say by the lifting lemma that our maps lifts to its universal cover $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is contractible, but I don't know if  this is relevant.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you do the analogous problem for $S^1$?

Comment: I guess its impossible for $S^1$ since it a path that wraps $S^1$ hence its not zero

Comment: My hunch is you can postcompose with a surjection to the circle to see that map must not be zero.

Comment: @TheGeometer: It's not impossible with $S^1$! First flatten your circle to an interval and then wrap the interval around the circle. So intuitively, your path travels around the circle so it is surjective, but then backtracks back to where it started, so it is degree $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an outline on constructing such a map.

I'm thinking of $S^1 = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}$.  Then define $g:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ by $g(z) = \begin{cases} z^2 & \operatorname{Im}(z)\geq 0\\ \overline{z}^2 & \operatorname{Im}(z)\leq 0\end{cases}$.

Note that if $\operatorname{Im}(z) = 0$, then $z = \pm 1$, so $z^2 = \overline{z}^2  =1$ in this case.  Thus, $g$ really is continuous.

Intuitively, $g$ wraps the top half of $S^1$ fully around $S^1$ one way, and wraps the bottom half of $S^1$ fully around $S^1$ the other way.

Can you prove $g$ is surjective?  Can you prove that $g$ is the $0$ map on $H_1$?  Can you use $g$ to construct $f:T\rightarrow T$ with the properties you're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

You can try also the following solution: Take any surjective continuous map from $T$ to $I$ - unit interval, for example a height function. Then using Peano curve you can find surjective continuous map from $I$ to $I^2$, and then the quotient map from $I^2$ to $T$. This map will be continuous and surjective, and induces $0$ in $H_1(X)$, since it factors through contractible space.

Actually, this map is null-homotopic.

To be totally fair, my friend gave me this solution, so I am not claiming I had this idea myself. Thanks Andrzej :)

Comment: This works but nothing this complicated is needed.

Comment: Maybe not, but that is basically the same idea as yours in the last comment under the post :)

Comment: Well, mapping to $S^1$ you don't need a space-filling curve. Then to do $S^1\times S^1$, just use my idea in each coordinate. Upvoted your answer, btw.

Comment: Yes, now I see. I can project a torus onto a square, and then back on a torus. Indeed simpler then using Peano curves